# How I can pass nested promises to async await

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I have a function that downloads a file from endpoint using filesaver.js the problem is that I need to pass the function to async await method

```
fileDownload = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/buildings/1/assets.xlsx')
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => saveAs(blob, 'assets.xlsx'))
}
```

How can change this to async await with this nested promises? (the function is ok)

Comment: returning the ```fetch``` will make ```fileDownload``` a promise you can use with await

Comment: Why do you need to pass this in as a promise to begin with? What does `saveAs` do? Right now this is just a function that performs an operation and doesn't return a value. But yes, you can use `return` in front of `fetch` and it will become a promise. But I'm wondering why you would need to make this code synchronous to begin with.

Comment: `pass the function to async await method` - what async await method? Do you understand that async/await is syntax sugar for promises, so, returning a promise is all you need to use `await`? note, your `fileDownload` does **not** return a promise

Answer (score 3):

You can use the code:

```
fileDownload = async () => {
    let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/buildings/1/assets.xlsx');
    let blob = await response.blob();
    await saveAs(blob, 'assets.xlxs');
};
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.